# Admob ad doesn`t show up in my android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I created ad via google admob console - and it even counted requests
I connected to firebase
I added admob ad in my android app according all instructions but it doesnot show up.
What is wrong?
Sorry - a lot of code but I just don`t understand where to dig

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.view.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/main_container"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AdView adView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, String.valueOf(R.string.google_app_id));
    //adding first visible fragment 
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment mainScreenFragment = new MainScreenFragment();
    //adding banner
    adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("7B0491EFFC06B1A3FBE6637394533EDE")
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    String tag = "MainScreen";
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, mainScreenFragment, tag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

First visible fragment(xml of MainScreenFragment.java)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.view.MainScreenFragment">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pay"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
          ....
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.appolinary.antiradar">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:name="com.appolinary.antiradar.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/google_app_id"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
        android:value="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".presentation.view.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

gradle

```
//admob
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:16.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete one of implementations in gradle (choose between firebase-ads:17.2.1, play-services-ads:17.2.1 because the shouldn't be together). Admob starts to show you ads when app start making more requests to evaluate your traffic. Also try reseting advertising id in settings on device that doesn't show ads.

Comment: I removed "firebase-ads:17.2.1" according to your advice.  I reseted advertising id. I reinstall adb (adb uninstall <package>). Same behavior :( And with simulator also :( I have ~120 requests (for last 2 days - from my testing device) and 0 display

Comment: How do I need to get banner_id if I have App.class inside my app? I need to point ....App in admob console? or it is not important?